# Documentations for tboot?

Tags: intel, trusted-computing

Is there any Documentation to understand what tboot does and how tboot works? 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tboot/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBoot is the reference implementation of a Measured Launched Environment in Intel TXT terms. In it's role as a MLE, TBoot can function as a boot loader and launch a whole operating system in this protected environment.

The Trusted Computing concept implemented is named *late-launch* or *Dynamic Root of Trust for Measurement (DRTM)*.

What it actually does is described in Intel's *[Trusted Execution Technology: Software Development Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software-developers/intel-txt-software-development-guide.html)*. TBoot implements functionality of the entities called *OS* and *MLE*.